# ZeroTier not working on router running FreshTomato firmware

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, iptables

0

I can successfully connect to my ZeroTier with the router and join my ZT network with an automatic IP assigned my ZT. However, I can’t ping the router from from any device on my ZT network nor have the router ping any device my my ZT network. However any device that’s connected to the router, be it Wi-Fi or wired, could ping all the devices on my ZT network.

My local network IP addresses are 192.168.1.* range and the ZeroTier network is 10.147.18.0/24 My guess its the Iptables rules or route that have to be added or some other configuration I’m missing. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed ZeroTier inside the router, or on the computer?

Comment: no its on the router itself using entware, any device on the ZT network is able to ping all other devices on the ZT network besides the router itself.

Comment: Without ZeroTier, is the router responding to pings?

Comment: Yes, the router is pingable on the LAN 192.168.1.1, its only any device on ZT network 10.147.18.0/24 which try to reach it or it attempts to reach them isn't able to. I have the ZT interface up on the routers routing table, what's missing is the proper Iptables rules for the interface to forward packets from the ZT interface to br0 interface.

Comment: Do [these rules](https://zerotier.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/224395274/Route+between+ZeroTier+and+Physical+Networks) help?

Comment: I already tried all of them already, I think they are mainly for open WRT not fresh tomato router firmware. Much appreciation however.